# Fetching integer and decimal part of a floating number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Given a floating point number like -102.123. How do I separate the integer part which is -102 and 
the decimal part which is 123. Is there some special instruction to do it or it needs to be done
thru some manual methods ? My ultimate aim is to convert it to binary so I am planning to convert 
the decimal part to binary separately and the integer part separately.

Comment: Do you want to use x87 or SSE instructions?

Comment: In normal terminology the fractional part would be `0.123`, not `123`.  Otherwise you have a problem: `-102.123 == -102.1230` but is the fractional part `123` or `1230`? Also, are you wanting the integer part as an actual integer, or as a floating-point value which represents an integer?

Comment: `x - trunc(x)` leaves the fractional part, which you can multiply by 100 if you want and then round that to integer.  That's a simplistic way which probably has rounding errors for some corner cases.  Note that the integer part of a float isn't guaranteed to fit in an int64_t; the exponent range is wider than 2^64.  So if you want to handle large floats as fixed-point, you'll need extended-precision integer, or some floating-point method to reduce the magnitude to fit in an integer.  (Note that a float only has 24 mantissa bits, so in fixed-point only 24 significant figures in base 2.)